# What are the missing proficiencies per level for the Oriental Adventures monk and yakuza?

Tags: monk, adnd-1e, proficiency

*Oriental Adventures* on the class **monk** says

> [T]he monk starts with proficiency in one style of unarmed combat and two of that style's special maneuvers. The monk also has five other proficiency slots. Of these, one must be used for religion and another calligraphy. The remaining slots can be filled as the player sees fit within the restrictions of the class." "All monks have the martial arts special maneuver Missile Deflection in addition to the other special maneuvers thay may have or gain. This is not considered part of any martial style and so does not use one of the special maneuver slots for the monk's chosen martial art. (18)

And on the **yakuza** it says

> Yakuza begin play with three proficiency slots available. In addition, they automatically have the gaming proficiency. (26)

Table 56 (*Oriental Adventures* 51) shows the proficiencies character classes gain when they advance levels except that the table omits the monk and the yakuza (51). **What are these missing values?**

#### For comparison

The *Player's Handbook* Weapon Proficiency Table and *Unearthed Arcana* show the following monk proficiences:

| Class of Character | Initial # of Prof | Add Proficiency per Level | Non-proficiency Weapon Penalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monk | 1 | 1/2 levels | -3 |

The *Dungeoneer's Survival Guide* on Table 10 (23) and *Wilderness Survival Guide* on Table 1 (12) have the same proficiency entries for the monk:

| Class of Character | Initial # of Proficiencies Weapon/Nonweapon | Add Proficiency per Level Weapon/Nonweapon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monk | 1/1 | 1/1 per 2 levels |

However, using *Oriental Adventures*, it seems like for the monk and yakuza this information is as follows:

| Class of Character | Initial # of Prof | Add Proficiency per Level | Non-proficiency Weapon Penalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monk | 5 | missing (possibly 1/1 per 2 levels?) | -3 from PHB and UA |
| Yakuza | 3 | missing | missing |

…And I'd like to fill in the missing information.

Comment: I thought that the *OA* monk was pretty much a different class from the *PH* monk, and that the *DSG* and the *WSG* reference the *PH* monk. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if that's accurate how is the information from the *DSG* and *WSG* relevant? (Have patience with me if, in fact, this is totally obvious; it's been a while since I *OA*ed.)

Comment: The DSG page 23 refers to non-weapon proficiencies from OA. My intent is to find some way to derive the missing non-weapon proficiency slots from DSG or WSG or at least provide the existing data as a conversation starter. Maybe there is a better way to derive non-weapon proficiencies.

Comment: I edited this a little to make clearer what I thought was the goal. Feel free to edit further or rollback, especially if I've misunderstood something or gotten it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Sage Advice column in Dragon Magazine #151

> **How many proficiencies do monks and yakuza get?**
>
> The following additions/changes apply to table 56 (page 51):
>
> | Class | Initial # of prof. | Add prof. per level | WNPP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Monk | 5 | 1/2 | -3 |
> | Yakuza | 3 | 1/3 | -3 |